# Difference between java.util.regex and org.apache.regexp?

Tags: java, regex, apache

I tried this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String regexp = "[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)*@[\\w-]+(\\.[\\w-]+)*(\\.)[a-zA-Z]+";    

        String text1 = "my.name-here@my.domain-here.ext";
        String text2 = "my.name-here@m@y.domain-here.ext";
        String text3 = "@domain-here.ext";
        String text4 = "my.name-here@";
        String text5 = "my.name-here@domain-here";
        String text6 = ".my.name-here@my.domain-here.ext";
        String text7 = "my.name-here.@my.domain-here.ext";
        String text8 = "my.name-here@.my.domain-here.ext";
        String text9 = "my.name-here@my.domain-here.ext.";
        String text10 = "my.na me-here@my.domain-here.ext";
        String text11 = "my.name-here@my.dom ain-here.ext";
        String text12 = "my..name-here@my.domain-here.ext";
        String text13 = "my.name-here@my..domain-here.ext";

        RE re = new RE(regexp);
        System.out.println(re.match(text1));
        System.out.println(re.match(text2));
        System.out.println(re.match(text3));
        System.out.println(re.match(text4));
        System.out.println(re.match(text5));
        System.out.println(re.match(text6));
        System.out.println(re.match(text7));
        System.out.println(re.match(text8));
        System.out.println(re.match(text9));
        System.out.println(re.match(text10));
        System.out.println(re.match(text11));
        System.out.println(re.match(text12));
        System.out.println(re.match(text13));

        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text1));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text2));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text3));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text4));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text5));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text6));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text7));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text8));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text9));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text10));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text11));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text12));
        System.out.println(Pattern.matches(regexp, text13));
    }
```

Only the first one must be right but... `org.apache.regexp.RE` does something wrong. Any solution? Thanks a lot. I have to do it with `org.apache.regexp.RE` obligatory.

**Update:** Pattern do matches right (all false except the first one), RE say someone String are true but they isn't.

Comment: Please provide further details! What exactly does not work using apache.regexp?

Comment: RE: "Please provide further details! What exactly does not work using apache.regexp?"

Pattern do matches right (all false except the first one), RE say someone String are true but they isnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression does not state that it must match the entire input and thus I assume within `my.name-here@m@y.domain-here.ext` Apache Regexp matches the `m@y.domain-here.ext` part (although I don't know Apache RegexP that well and it is retired, btw).

Wrap your regex with ^ and $ to make it match the entire input.

From the JavaDoc on `Matcher#matches()` (`Pattern.matches(...)` calls that method as you can see from its JavaDoc):

> Attempts to match the *entire* region against the pattern

*Edit*

I just tested your expression in the RegexP applet and it seems like you have to escape the literal `-` in your character classes (which is good practice anyways). This expression seems to work in RegexP:

```
"^[\\w\\-]+(\\.[\\w\\-]+)*@[\\w\\-]+(\\.[\\w\\-]+)*(\\.)[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

Btw, you might want to add non-capturing groups to optimize the expression a bit, i.e. instead of `(\\.)` you'd write `(?:\\.)` etc.

Comment: OMG thanks! This was the problem! Pattern doesn't need to escape the "-" character contrary to apache regexp :D

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to offer a side note answer here.  Sadly email regular expressions are almost universally wrong.  Here is the valid regex for email addresses as described by the standard.
http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

I would note that `"hi@dog"@example.com` is a valid email address and is not valid for use at many websites due to the one `@` in the regex.

Comment: Thanks about your answer, i think like you, but this regex is based on external request. My intention is that "hi@dog"@example.com returns false.

Comment: Actually, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) has a good general use expression for RFC822 addresses. They also state there's a much shorter and much more readable expression that still matches 99.9% of all email addresses in use due to the fact that double quoted addresses and the like are very rarely used.